# XSLT translation issue matching substring text

Tags: xml, xslt

I am looking for some help with an XSLT i am trying to create - the issue i am trying to work is that if attributeId contains the substring "fault_code", i want to get the value of AttributeAssignment:

INPUT:

```
 <AttributeAssignment AttributeId="att_obl_authorization_rule_fault_code" DataType="string" Issuer="" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment">ERROR</At‌​tributeAssignment>
```

XSLT Ive tried:

```
<xsl:template match="AttributeAssignment">
  <xsl:if test="contains=('{@AttributeId}', 'fault_code')" > 
    <faultcode> soapenv:<xsl:value-of select='.'/> 
    </faultcode> 
     </xsl:if> 
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This:**

```
<xsl:if test="contains=('{@AttributeId}', 'fault_code')" >
```

**is not valid. Use this instead:**

```
<xsl:if test="contains(@AttributeId, 'fault_code')" >
```

---

**To test, when this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="AttributeAssignment">
    <xsl:if test="contains(@AttributeId, 'fault_code')">
      <faultcode>soapenv:<xsl:value-of select="."/></faultcode>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...or this simpler, more extensible XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="AttributeAssignment[contains(@AttributeId, 'fault_code')]">
    <faultcode>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('soapenv:', .)"/>
    </faultcode>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the provided XML:***

```
<AttributeAssignment AttributeId="att_obl_authorization_rule_fault_code" DataType="string" Issuer="" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:environment">ERROR</AttributeAssignment>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
<faultcode>soapenv:ERROR</faultcode>
```